JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService not working with AadWebApplicationHttpSecurityConfigurer but did with AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
After migrating from Spring Cloud Azure 4.x to 5.x, the JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService no longer seems to save the "OAuth2 Authorized Client".
Previous 4.6 code:
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories
public class AzureOauthClientConfiguration extends AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**")
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations, ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(jdbcOperations, clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
}

and the 5.x equivalent:
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity()
@EnableJdbcRepositories
public class AzureOauthClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.apply(AadWebApplicationHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadWebApplication())
                    .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                    .authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations, ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(jdbcOperations, clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
}

The internal code of both AAD classes seem effectively equivalent. Any pointers on how to make this work or why it no longer works?

Not sure if this is the best/correct way, but adding the below bean to the configuration worked:
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    return new AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientService);
}

